# Why won't ASP.NET download .py or .apk files?

Tags: html, asp.net, razor, download

I'm new to ASP.NET and Razor pages but this makes no sense. I'm trying to download a few files from a webpage and it's not working. I switched from hosting the static pages raw(no ASP.NET) where it worked but once I switched to ASP.NET it didn't work. I've been able to download .exe, .pdf, .zip, and .txt files but not .py or .apk files.

Whenever I try to download a .py or .apk file it says Failed - No File, but all the other file types download fine.

So to start these worked:

```
<a href="~/Trevor Stauffer-Resume.pdf" download="Trevor Stauffer-Resume.pdf">Download My Resume</a>
<a href="./FinanceTrackerApplication.zip" download="FinanceTrackerApplication.zip">Code</a>
<a href="/FinanceTrackerApplication.exe" download="FinanceTrackerApplication.exe">Release</a>
<a href="ReadMe.txt" download="ReadMe.txt">ReadMe</a>
```

These did not:

```
<a href="~/akashic.apk" download="akashic.apk" type="application/vnd.android.package-archive">Release</a>
<a download="Euler70.py" href="~/Euler70.py">Euler70.py</a>
<a href="~/Euler70SecondAttempt.py" download="Euler70SecondAttempt.py">Euler70SecondAttempt.py</a>
<a href="~/Euler70ThirdAttempt.py" download="Euler70ThirdAttempt.py" type="text/plain">Euler70ThirdAttempt.py</a>
```

I've tried with and without specifying type. I've tried href="~/Euler70.py", href="/Euler70.py", href=".Euler70.py" and href="Euler70.py" none worked.

I included all the files to download directly in my wwwroot folder and they are all spelled correctly.

My directory:

```
Project
|
|-----Properties
|     |-----launchSettings.json
|
|-----wwwroot
|     |-----css
|     |-----js
|     |-----lib
|     |-----akashic.py
|     |-----Euler70.py
|     |-----Euler70SecondAttempt.py
|     |-----Euler70ThirdAttempt.py
|     |-----favicon.ico
|     |-----FinanceTrackerApplication.exe
|     |-----FinanceTrackerApplication.zip
|     |-----me.jpg
|     |-----ReadMe.txt
|     |-----Trevor Stauffer-Resume.pdf
|
|-----Pages
|     |-----Shared
|     |-----_ViewImports.cshtml
|     |-----_ViewStart.cshtml
|     |-----Contact.cshtml
|     |-----Error.cshtml
|     |-----Index.cshtml
|
|-----appsettings.json
|-----Dockerfile
|-----Program.cs
```

My Index.cshtml is a basic PageModel file with an empty OnGet function:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace TrevorsResume.Pages
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;

        public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public void OnGet()
        {

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: *"it says Failed - No File"* - What specifically "says" this exact message?  In your browser's debugging tools, what is the URL of the request being made when clicking on the link?  Is that URL what you expect?  What is the server's response?

Comment: What web server? Perhaps it's missing mime mappings and therefore refusing to serve the .py and .apk files.

Comment: Chrome says "Failed - No File" in the download box. The URL request is "https://localhost:7033/Euler70.py" which is what I expect. To be honest I'm not sure how to find the server's response

Comment: Hit F12 and see the Network tab to discover what response you're actually getting.

Comment: It's local web server running on ASP.NET Razor pages. Does type="text/plain" provide mapping for .py file and type="application/vnd.android.package-archive" provide mapping .apk?

Comment: What is "a local web server"? Which server specifically? And no, the `type=` attribute instructs the browser, not the server.

Comment: I hit F12 clicked a couple downloads and I didn't see a response in the network tab not even a Not_Found response even when I clicked a download that worked. I clicked a link that changed pages then I saw a bunch of 200 Responses

Comment: OK that might answer my question then. I just need to find how to instruct the server

Answer (score 2):

To solve it I added the following to my program.cs file which adds MIME mappings for the server for .py and .apk files:

```
var provider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
provider.Mappings[".py"] = "text/plain";
provider.Mappings[".apk"] = "application/vnd.android.package-archive";
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    ContentTypeProvider = provider
});
```

program.cs became:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

var provider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
provider.Mappings[".py"] = "text/plain";
provider.Mappings[".apk"] = "application/vnd.android.package-archive";
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    ContentTypeProvider = provider
});


app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```